# Get RST right after OCI function call

Tags: .net, oracle12c

I have a business layer .NET program connecting .NET front end application and backend Oracle 12c database. When I come in office and run the application first time. I always get a time out error on application server. I looked at error log on business layer server and found Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-03135: connection lost contact. I installed wireshark. The following two packets seems to be the problem. It looks like the application sends out database function call without handshake. I can see a lot of handshake packets after this between business server and database server. The application will run smoothly after this first blow out. What could be the cause of this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off pooling in connection string. It starts to work now. It seems Oracle .net library has issue with idle pooling sessions.